# Ionic 2 : looking for modules in app app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)

Tags: ionic2

getting error when `serve` ionic 2 app.

```
'looking for modules in app
    app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' ionic-anguler in app
      resolve file
        app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist
        app/ionic-anguler.js doesn't exist'
```

home.js

```
    import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Page2} from '../page2/page2';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'

})
export class HomePage {
    static get parameters(){
        return [[NavController]];
    }

    constructor(nav){
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    go_to_page_2(){
        this.nav.push(Page2);
    }
}
```

error log

```
./app/pages/home/home.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ionic-anguler' in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/app/pages/home
resolve module ionic-anguler in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/app/pages/home
  looking for modules in app
    app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' ionic-anguler in app
      resolve file
        app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist
        app/ionic-anguler.js doesn't exist
  looking for modules in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules
    /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' ionic-anguler in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules
      resolve file
        /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler doesn't exist
        /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler.js doesn't exist
[app/ionic-anguler]
[app/ionic-anguler]
[app/ionic-anguler.js]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler.js]
 @ ./app/pages/home/home.js 12:20-44,./app/pages/page2/page2.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ionic-anguler' in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/app/pages/page2
resolve module ionic-anguler in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/app/pages/page2
  looking for modules in app
    resolve 'file' ionic-anguler in app
      resolve file
        app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist
        app/ionic-anguler.js doesn't exist
    app/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules
    resolve 'file' ionic-anguler in /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules
      resolve file
        /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler doesn't exist
        /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler.js doesn't exist
    /Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler doesn't exist (module as directory)
[app/ionic-anguler]
[app/ionic-anguler.js]
[app/ionic-anguler]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler.js]
[/Users/kosala/Desktop/IonicProjects/test_three/app/node_modules/ionic-anguler]
 @ ./app/pages/page2/page2.js 10:20-44 (CLI v2.0.0-beta.19)
```

Comment: Have you checked this one already? Upcoming Ionic 2 Starter Changes https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/attention-upcoming-ionic-2-starter-changes/45058

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Should be `ionic-angular` instead of `ionic-anguler`.

Comment: im still getting error.update question with new error log

Comment: It still says "ionic-angul**E**r", not "ionic-angul**A**r"